# Einstein Bot: get current Community User for Live Agent Pre-Chat

Tags: apex, customer-community, liveagent, einstein

I'm playing around with Einstein Bots and have created a simple bot that is consumed inside a customer community.

I'd like to get the current User inside an Apex action used in a bot dialog.

The `UserInfo.getUserId()`, as expected, returns the *Automated Process* system user.

Are there system slots (like `LiveAgentSessionId`) that can be used for this porpouse?

In my mynd the only way to get the running user is to create a custom lightning component that would grab the UserId and pass it to the Bot without actually asking for anything from the running user...but honestly it seems more a workaround.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
I found a workaround on this but it seems robust enough. Here are the details: https://blog.enree.co/2018/11/salesforce-dealing-with-the-running-user-on-einstein-bot-dialogs.html

Comment: Since you mention LiveAgentSessionId, are you inside LiveAgent with this bot? If so, you'll want to refer to the [Live Agent Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_dev_guide_intro.htm). If not, then explaining how the bot interacts with the community user might be more helpful. My guess would be that you'll need a controller for a component to get the info if you don't use embedded visualforce in an I frame inside the component.

Comment: I've created a custom lightning component that is able to get the current running user, but when I put the Snap-Ins component on the home page of the customer community, I find no way to tell the prechat that you can have an additional field, that is the UserId. I've tried with the community builder "Extrnal Scripts" for the chat snap-in component, but no luck so far to pass another parameter.

Comment: I've seen a lot of questions asked about getting things to work with the pre-chat app on SF.SE. I suggest you search on it to see if it turns up anything useful because I know it's a difficult app to work with that I do not think is well documented. That thing is conditioned to look for a contact and probably doesn't want to think in terms of community users. I don't know if there are any real limits on how many fields it can use. Hopefully someone else will jump in after seeing this. I will edit your title and tags to draw attention to your post.

Answer (score 3):

I've come up with a solution that seems to be working to get back the logged in community user details.

You need to override PreChat Lightning Components with your own custom components. This needs to be configured in the Live Agent Settings on your `Snap-In`.

Use a `Controller`(Apex Class) on your custom Pre Chat Component to get logged in user details on `onInit`. This will run in System Context and you'll be able to get the user details.

Now use these details to set the pre-chat fields like `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email` etc. Validate and Start the Chat. You'll see the Bot now has Pre-Chat data.

Secondly, add a `Apex` `Invocation` call at the start in Welcome Message, pass `LiveAgentSessionId` as a parameter. Fetch the `LiveChatTranscript`. Since, we've already set the Pre-Chat fields and mapped the contact the `LiveChatTranscipt` will have the correct Contact mapped too. Just pass these details back to the Bot.

This way your Bot now also has the Contact details.

Have tested it and it works on a Community with Einstein Bot deployed via Snap-in.

Comment: Hi Shantanu! Thank you! This is the same solution I came up with but the problem is that using the contact details is not the best solution as there is no guarantee that you are referring to the current user. What I'm looking for is a way to pass to the chat the user id/username to be passed to the Live Chat transcript...if you use custom snap-in snippet on an external web page or in visualforce you have plain control on the configurations, but using a lightning ocmponent inside a snap-in community component it's not that easy to setup :(

Comment: That's correct, using standard lightning snap-in has very limited customisable options at the moment. All processes running from Bot's context will be owned by Cloud Integration User. We can fire Platform Events but those will be run via the Automated User. 
The solution I presented can capture the Community logged in user.
These are the only 3 users which will be running processes when interacting with the Bot. Checked your question again not sure which other user would you need info about?

Comment: I guess this is the answer I was lookgin for :( https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228053/is-it-possible-read-write-settings-of-embedded-svc-in-lightning-component-of-pre

Comment: Yeah, I've referred to this answer for more understanding earlier too. Sorry, missed to direct you to it.

Comment: I found a solution, I'll document it on a post on my blog and link it here later...it's a workaround but it works.

Comment: https://blog.enree.co/2018/11/salesforce-dealing-with-the-running-user-on-einstein-bot-dialogs.html

Comment: Was anyone able to do it without the Pre-Chat form?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible. The user in the snapping is an integration user. “Login” like a customer, is not possible

Comment: You can actually use the pre-chst by adding the current user to the Transcript object, but so far I couldn't make it work using snap-ins + community + standard snap-ins component in builder

Comment: But pre-chat Is not a "secure" Login. I think Is better ask something to customer and use a second authenticator factor to verify who is talking with you

Comment: I meant that in the pre-chat I know if I'm logged at all and send the proper info to the chat apis.